# VPN - same local/remote IP range

Tags: vpn

I've configured VPN on my router however I can't access any device behind the router when I'm using the same subnet on the client. The whole network and router are running on: 192.168.1.0/24.
It works fine when I'm connected from different subnet.

Could you please advise how to solve this issue as most of the home users will probably have the same 192.168.1.0/24 subnet so they won't be able to access any device behind the router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

renumber either of the networks or use address translation if it's appropriate for the protocols that will flow over the vpn